# d3.js line graph not displaying correctly in Safari

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari, d3.js

I've followed the d3.js tutorials on how to make a line graph and it is working successfully/displaying properly in Chrome (v24.0.1312.56) but not in Safari (v6.0.2 (7536.26.17)). In Safari the axes display properly, but the line itself has the endpoints plotted outside of the svg and it is stretched across the entire canvas. You can see it here:

http://www.npcompleteheart.com/post/time-series-plotting-d3js/

I also put the code in a jsfiddle but I'm not sure how to make it work right now (first time using it):
http://jsfiddle.net/hFRZx/15/

The only change in the jsfiddle is that there is a data variable instead of the actual json file location.

I have tried:

- Not plotting the circles on the lines and removing tipsy
- The SVG was originally appended to a div, I switched to having a svg in the HTML with the height and width set. Then setting the height and width upon the graph creation to "100%".

What I do know is that the values for the path are not the same in Chrome as they are in Safari.  I'm unfortunately stuck as to why because there is only this line that plots the path in the code (not much to it):

```
 graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line1(data)).attr("class", "data1");
```

Relevant code for the graph creation is:

```
var dates = [];
var data = [];
var pointRadius = 1.75;

$.getJSON("/json/file/location.json", function(json) {
  $.each(json, function(key,value) {
    data.push(value)
    var eptime = new Date(parseFloat(key) * 1000)
    dates.push(eptime)
   });

  var margin = 110
  var m = [margin/3.5, margin, margin/3.5, margin]; // margins
  var w = 800 - m[1] - m[3];     // width
  var h = 500 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

  var x = d3.time.scale().domain([dates[0], dates[dates.length -1]]).range([0, w]);
  x.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"));
  var digitLength = 100000
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([Math.floor(d3.min(data, function(d) { return d; })/digitLength)*digitLength, 
                        d3.max(data, function(d) { return d; })])
    .range([h,0]);

  var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { 
            return x(dates[i]);
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
            return y(d);
    })
  var graph = d3.select("#timeseries_main")
                            .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                            .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                          .append("svg:g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(9).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(1);

  graph.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


  var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(7).orient("left");
  graph.append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)")
      .call(yAxisLeft);

  graph.append("text")
      .attr("class", "y label")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("y", -110)
      .attr("x", -140)
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Quantity X"); 
  graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line1(data)).attr("class", "data1");

  dataCirclesGroup = graph.append('svg:g');
  var circles = dataCirclesGroup.selectAll('.data-point')
    .data(data);

  circles
    .enter()
      .append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'data-point')
        .style('opacity', 1e-6)
        .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return x(dates[i]) })
        .attr('cy', function() { return y(0) })
        .attr('r', function() { return (data.length) ? pointRadius : 0 })
      .transition()
        .style('opacity', 1)
        .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return x(dates[i]) })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d) });

  circles
    .transition()
      .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return x(dates[i]) })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d) })
      .attr('r', function() { return (data.length) ? pointRadius : 0 })
      .attr('index', function(d,i) { return i; })
      .style('opacity', 1);

  circles
    .exit()
      .transition()
        .attr('cy', function() { return y(0) })
        .style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .remove();


    $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
      gravity: 'w', 
      html: true, 
      title: function() {
        var d = this.__data__;
        return numberWithCommas(d) + 
               '<br/> on ' + dates[$(this).attr("index")]; 
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked it in my safari 6.0.5 and it's OK. There're many bugs coming with svg. If you find one, you can post entire description to the browser developers, like [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=196523).